# Table only sorting Alphabetically, not Numerically

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, html-table

I have a table that is being populated by PHP variables. The PHP values are coming from JSON from an API.

I want to sort alphabetically and numerically in the same table.

The function below works, but only sorts it properly alphabetically.

Can I modify this function to also sort numerically?

```
<script>
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is just your JavaScript. Without the HTMl and/or PHP we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  var regex = /\$|USD|EURO|,/gi;
  var xinnerHTML="", yinnerHTML="";

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          shouldSwitch = false;
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];


      xinnerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(regex, '');
      yinnerHTML = y.innerHTML.replace(regex, '');

                var xContent = (isNaN(xinnerHTML))
    ? (xinnerHTML.toLowerCase() === '-')
        ? 0 : xinnerHTML.toLowerCase()
    : parseFloat(xinnerHTML);
var yContent = (isNaN(yinnerHTML))
    ? (yinnerHTML.toLowerCase() === '-')
        ? 0 : yinnerHTML.toLowerCase()
    : parseFloat(yinnerHTML);
      if (dir == "asc") {
          if (xContent > yContent) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
          }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
          if (xContent < yContent) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
  } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
          dir = "desc";
          switching = true;
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please paste the entire code, also showing me where the new function should be placed? It's not running properly.

Comment: Okay i pasted already. try it now.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it's still not working. Does it matter if the data in the chart is coming from JSON code and is stored in a PHP variable?

Comment: I've added new code in a new answer above. Can you please take a look at that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed direction and found new code that works. However, it will not sort numerically if there are numbers and letters in the same cell. How would I do this? I will paste new code below.

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          shouldSwitch = false;
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
                var xContent = (isNaN(x.innerHTML))
    ? (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === '-')
        ? 0 : x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()
    : parseFloat(x.innerHTML);
var yContent = (isNaN(y.innerHTML))
    ? (y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === '-')
        ? 0 : y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()
    : parseFloat(y.innerHTML);
      if (dir == "asc") {
          if (xContent > yContent) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
          }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
          if (xContent < yContent) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount ++;
  } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
          dir = "desc";
          switching = true;
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This should sort correctly, I guess.

Comment: It will work as long as their are not any special characters such as "$50" or "50 USD". Is there a way to sort numerically when there are other characters in the same cell?

Comment: You can remove the dollar or usd chars before you check isNan() like this:
var regex = /\$|USD/gi; x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML.replace(regex, ''); do the same with y.innerHTML

Comment: Thank you, but I am not a programmer. Can you please paste the new code with your new modifications? I tried a few things, but it's not running properly. Thank you again.

Comment: I edited my answer, I just modified your answer to implement JS replace. To remove $, USD, EURO etc. You can add more currency in the regex var.

Comment: Thank you. However, this code only seems to sort the first number. For example:
110, then 
199, then 
3,210, and then 
358

Comment: You try. i edited a bit. I remove , too.

Comment: Also, after sorting, the special characters disappear. How do I reinsert the missing characters?

Comment: No need to insert special chars. Try the modified answer.